# Returning array of matched substrings

Tags: jquery, regex, prototype

I have this beautiful function, but I need to customize it to return just an array of items matching the regex.  so the result would be `#hash1234, #sweetthing,#something_notimportant`  Is there any way to do this using this function?

```
String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
    return this.replace(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(t) {
        var tag = t.replace("#", "%23");
        return t.link("http://search.twitter.com/search?q=" + tag);
    });
};

var string = '#hash1234 this is another hash: #sweetthing and yet another #something_notimportant';       
$('#result').html(string.parseHashtag());
```

Comment: `'#hash1234 this is another hash: #sweetthing and yet another #something_notimportant'.match(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g).join(", ")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.match` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array of all matches, or `null` if there were no matches.

So if `null` is an acceptable return for the no-match situation then:

```
String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
    return this.match(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g);
}
```

Or if you'd prefer to return an empty array or other default for no-match:

```
String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
    return this.match(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g) || [];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
String.prototype.findHashTags = function() {
    return this.match(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g);
};

string.findHashTags()
// returns ["#hash1234", "#sweetthing", "#something_notimportant"]
```

The pattern is exactly the same.

Comment: You're welcome. +1, and sorry for posting almost the same answer, but I'd started typing mine before I saw yours and I wanted to include the information about what would happen when there was no match so when I saw that you hadn't talked about that I went ahead with mine...

Answer (score 0):

use match.

```
String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
    var t= this.match(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g);
    var tag='';
   $.each(t,function(index,value) { tag = tag + value.replace('#','%23') + ','; });
    return "http://search.twitter.com/search?q=" + tag;

};

var string = '#hash1234 this is another hash: #sweetthing and yet another #something_notimportant';       
$('#result').html(string.parseHashtag());​
```